# pgf-plot: y-axis shows comma instead of decimal point

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, punctuation

The ticks of the y-axis have to be displayed with a decimal point instead of a comma.

[image]

I have no idea how to do that. I'm using `\usepackage[english]{babel}` and even the commad `\decimalpoint` does not influence the axis.

Can anybody help me?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
title=SubstanceX,
title style={at={(0.5,0.75)}},
    ybar,
    enlarge x limits={rel=0.2},
    enlarge y limits={rel=0, lower},
    enlarge y limits={rel=0.1, upper},
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.15)},
    anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Peak area},
    symbolic x coords={Methanol,Methane,Acetone},
    xtick=data,
    bar width=8pt,
    width=7cm,
    height=6cm,] 
        \addplot[fill=white,draw=black, pattern = north west lines] coordinates {(Methanol,490929) (Methane,2921923) (Acetone,14153210};
        \addplot[fill=black!30!white,draw=black] coordinates {(Methanol,565207) (Methane,3965437) (Acetone,9296461)};
        \addplot[fill=white,draw=black] coordinates {(Methanol,504176) (Methane,3799790) (Acetone,3847704)};
        \addplot[fill=black,draw=black] coordinates {(Methanol,370737) (Methane,2897485) (Acetone,2373782)};
\legend{5 \%, 10 \%, 15 \%, 20 \%}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please provide a complete [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that produces this result. When I try your code I have an error so we need to know about your preamble and settings.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. I still see a dot and not a comma. What other packages/options are you using? Are you redefining something in your preamble?

Comment: To change from 'point' to 'comma', you usually set `\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}`. Check if you perhaps copied this line of code by accident somewhere in your .tex files.

Comment: @alesc That's what I was thinking too. Maybe he has redefined the command somewhere (unknowingly). It can happen if you use parts of codes from elsewhere.

Comment: @alesc Would you like to turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Wouldn't the answer be too short?

Comment: @alesc No, don't think so. The OP posted a (now deleted) answer that was basically a reiteration of your comment anyway. I guess either you answer, or we close as off topic.

Answer (score 7):

Your question lacks a minimal working example, so I'm going to make some assumptions.

Since PGFplots use decimal point by default, and since you also explicitely use `\usepackage[english]{babel}` and `\decimalpoint`, my best guess is that somewhere in your code (or in other includes) you have this line present:

```
\pgfplotsset{/pgf/number format/use comma}
```

Therefore make a global search throught your files for `use comma` and remove any entries you may find.

Comment: That's actually the result I was looking for! Present my pgfplots with comma as decimal separator, thanks for you answer.